# Passing array of query results to jQuery Autocomplete source attribute

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I'm struck up with an issue when tried to pass the query results to the jquery autocomplete's source attribute...

```
    <cfloop query="MyQuery">
      <cfset head=#ValueList(MyQuery.pname,",")#>
      <cfset head1=#listtoarray(head)#>
    </cfloop>
```

Here I want to send the head1 array to the jquery code,
Jquery autocomplete code goes as follows..

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>

    $(function() {
    var availableTags = head1;
    $("#k").autocomplete({
    source:availableTags
      });

  });


 </script>
 </cfif>
```

How to pass head1 to the availableTags

Comment: what is the contents of availableTags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First,
your cfloop is doing nothing but running `valuelist` and `listtoarray` over and over with the same results. There's no point in putting that in a query loop. See the details on [valueList](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6d19.html)

You can simply do something like this in your CF:

```
<cfset head=#ValueList(MyQuery.pname,",")#>
<cfset head1=#listtoarray(head)#>
```

ColdFusion has a nice function called [toScript](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e9d.html) that

> Creates a JavaScript or ActionScript expression that assigns the value
>   of a ColdFusion variable to a JavaScript or ActionScript variable.
>   This function can convert ColdFusion strings, numbers, arrays,
>   structures, and queries to JavaScript or ActionScript syntax that
>   defines equivalent variables and values.

To create your JS array using your CF array you can do the following:

```
$(function() {
    <cfoutput>var #ToScript(head1, "availableTags")#;</cfoutput>
    $("#k").autocomplete({
        source:availableTags
    });
});
```

The output of toScript looks something like

```
var availableTags =  new Array();
availableTags[0] = "something";
availableTags[1] = "something else";
availableTags[2] = "another something";
availableTags[3] = "even more something";
```

Answer (score 0):

I Used serializeJson to solve the issue..and you just gave me another good method... (toScript)...Thank You... :)

```
$(function() {
     <cfoutput>var states = <cfoutput>#serializeJson(head1)#</cfoutput>                                                                                             $("#k").autocomplete({
     source:availableTags
  });
  });
```